# Diff between values in different rows, based on timediff

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions

MariaDB version 10.4.10.

I have a stock scraper script that fetches stock data every hour and inserts it into a MySQL database. I want a way to get price difference for each stock between, for example:

- stocks fetched at 2020-03-25 07:00 and 2020-03-25 19:00 (12 hours)
- stocks fetched at 2020-03-25 07:00 and 2020-03-26 07:00 (24 hours)
- stocks fetched at 2020-03-25 08:00 and 2020-03-25 20:00 (12 hours)
- stocks fetched at 2020-03-25 08:00 and 2020-03-26 08:00 (24 hours)
  etc

The database structure looks something like this:

```
stocks( time_fetched DATETIME, name VARCHAR, price INT )
```

Some sample data:

```
**time_fetched          name        price**
2020-03-25 07:00:00     stock_A     10
2020-03-25 07:00:00     stock_B     14
2020-03-25 08:00:00     stock_A     12
2020-03-25 08:00:00     stock_B     20
...
2020-03-25 19:00:00     stock_A     28
2020-03-25 19:00:00     stock_B     32
2020-03-25 20:00:00     stock_A     40
2020-03-25 20:00:00     stock_B     36
...
2020-03-26 07:00:00     stock_A     12
2020-03-26 07:00:00     stock_B     16
2020-03-26 08:00:00     stock_A     18
2020-03-26 08:00:00     stock_B     16
```

Expected result:

```
**time_fetched            name        current_price     price_12h_ago     price_24h_ago**
2020-03-25 19:00:00     stock_A     28                10                NULL
2020-03-25 19:00:00     stock_B     32                14                NULL
2020-03-25 20:00:00     stock_A     40                12                NULL
2020-03-25 20:00:00     stock_B     36                20                NULL
2020-03-26 07:00:00     stock_A     12                28                10
2020-03-26 07:00:00     stock_B     16                32                14
2020-03-26 08:00:00     stock_A     18                40                12
2020-03-26 08:00:00     stock_B     16                36                20
```

Currently I am using SQL similar to this:

```
WITH prices AS (
  SELECT time_fetched, name, price,
         LAG(price, 12) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_fetched) AS price_12h_ago,
         LAG(price, 24) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_fetched) AS price_24h_ago
  FROM stocks
)
SELECT time_fetched, name, price AS current_price, price_12h_ago, price_24h_ago
FROM prices
```

This works, given that all stocks have price data fetched for all hours. **In reality, there are sometimes gaps beetween hours, and price data for some hours and some stocks are missing in the stocks database.**

This means that the above code that fetches price on 12 rows before the current one, does not always represent 12 hours before current row.

So I would need a way to get price difference based on actual timediff.

Hope this makes any sense to anyone out there :)

Comment: Is your all fetch time fixed?

Comment: Yes, with minute precision. The scraper script runs every hour, but the results can diff with a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range()` clause.  If your times are precise:

```
SELECT time_fetched, name, price,
       MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY name
                        ORDER BY time_fetched
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 12 hour AND INTERVAL 12 hour
                       ) as price_12h_ago,
       MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY name
                        ORDER BY time_fetched
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 24 hour AND INTERVAL 24 hour
                       ) as price_24h_ago
FROM stocks;
```

Unless you set the minutes and seconds to exactly `0`, you may want a broader range than just an instant.  For instance:

```
SELECT time_fetched, name, price,
       MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY name
                        ORDER BY time_fetched
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '12:05' HOUR_MINUTE AND INTERVAL '11:55' HOUR_MINUTE
                       ) as price_12h_ago,
       MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY name
                        ORDER BY time_fetched
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '24:05' HOUR_MINUTE AND INTERVAL '23:55' HOUR_MINUTE
                       ) as price_24h_ago
FROM stocks;
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it could work. I do however get an error when testing: "check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERVAL 12 HOUR". Should it not be "RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 12 HOUR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" instead? That also gives me a syntax error like the one above. Not sure why. Should be possible to use RANGE and INTERVAL together with PARTITION BY I believe?

Comment: @thans . . . (1) The intention is to get 12 hours before.  You could also use `first_value()`, but you wouldn't know if it is really 12 hours before.  (2) MySQL supports ranges with intervals.  I assume MariaDB does as well, but perhaps it does not.